# Can't use classes from different Maven modules

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, module, pom.xml

Need to create a multi module maven project which consist of a registration module and main project. The problem is that it's impossible to use classes declared in different modules.

e.g.: I have a `ParentClaz` in my parent's src/main/java dir and `ChildClaz` in child's src/main/java dir. Right now it's not possible to use neither `ParentClaz` in `ChildClaz` nor vice versa.

The project's structure looks like this:

```
+-- AdminPortal     <- parent root
   +-- registration <- child root
       -- pom.xml   <- child pom
   -- pom.xml       <- parent pom
```

my AdminPortal POM:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>AdminPortal</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>AdminPortal</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<modules>
    <module>registration</module>
</modules>
```

Here's child POM:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>AdminPortal</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.example.AdminPortal</groupId>
<artifactId>registration</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>registration</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
```

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your parent pom has packaging type `pom`, this is not `jar`. This is special aggregator module. All java code should be located in `jar` modules.

Module with packaging type `pom` cant generate artifacts like jar, war or ear.

[Maven by Example - The Simple Parent Project](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-parent.html)

> The parent project doesn’t create a JAR or a WAR like our previous projects; instead, it is simply a POM that refers to other Maven projects.

To use Classes from one module in other module use maven dependency.

Typical project looks like this:

```
* administration project (pom)
   * registration (jar)
   * portal (war)
```

Comment: So you mean I should declare my main project as jar/war and make some AdminPortal-parent  module, which includes AdminPortal and registration module?

Comment: yes, your parent pom can have many modules like jar and war. All your source code should be located in modules

Comment: Sure, I will mark it as a solution some minutes later (system doesn't let to choose the right answer faster then 10-15 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

Child can use parent dependencies, try to add this to parent

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and make this class in child

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class);
    }
}
```

and you will see that it compiles.

Comment: The problem is code located inside parent pom module :) You cant attach source code from pom to jar module.

Comment: You can put code in parent as OP, but this is useless ofcours :) Read the question: *I have a ParentClaz **in my parent's** src/main/java dir and ChildClaz in child's src/main/java dir.*