# Trouble importing Spring's ReflectionTestUtils class

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, spring-test

I'm working on a multi-module maven project called *acme-platform*, with the modules set up like so:

1. acme-admin
2. acme-common
3. acme-global
4. acme-services
5. acme-client
6. acme-registration
7. acme-properties
8. acme-test

(They are listed in this order in the *acme-platform* pom.)

In some of the modules, I have been able to use Spring's ReflectionTestUtils class.  However, in the last module, *acme-test*, where I really want to use it, I am unable to.  There was no dependency section in the *acme-test* pom, so I added one.  Here is the pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>acme-platform</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.awesomeness.acme</groupId>
    <version>1.21.0</version>
    <relativePath>../</relativePath>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>acme-test</artifactId>
<version>1.21.0</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Before adding the dependency lines, I couldn't import any of Spring's api into my classes.  After importing these lines, I was able to access most of the classes, but not all of them, and in particular not ReflectionTestUtils, even though it is part of the spring-test module (as can be verified **[here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.java)**).

I am using Intellij.  I have looked at answers to other questions (such as **[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992255/how-can-i-make-intellij-update-my-dependencies-from-maven)**) to make sure I'm updating my dependencies correctly.  To no avail.

Does anyone have any idea as to why I can't import `org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils` into *acme-test*?

Let me know if you need any aditional information.

**EDIT**

The version information of the dependencies are not in any of the module poms, but they are specified in the root pom (*acme-platform*).  Again, I can import ReflectionTest in the other modules, just not in *acme-test*.  So I deduce from this that as long as the dependency is declared with a specified version in the root pom, it doesn't need a version specified in any of the module poms.  (If I'm wrong on this, please correct me.)

**ADDITIONAL EDIT**

By the way, I can't import junit either.

---

Comment: Hope that you have mentioned `<version>` inside the `<dependency>` tag

Comment: I did not mention the version, but in my understanding, I don't think I need to, because it is working in the other modules and they don't mention the version.  The version is being taken care of in the project pom.

I'm updating my question to include this information.

Comment: Could one of the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006565/cant-use-classes-from-different-maven-modules) help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the Maven `scope` to `test` for both the `spring-test` and `junit` dependencies.

For example:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```